# What DB the strapi uses built by --quickstart option?

Tags: strapi

I started touching strapi with this document on my ubuntu machine.
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/getting-started/quick-start.html#_1-install-strapi-globally

And it seems working fine now.

[image]

My question is, what DB is working for this strapi server?

Looking configuration, it seems working on MongoDB(see above picuture)

However, I didn't touch about MongoDB since there's no comment about MongoDB in tutorial. And in fact MongoDB is not on my server.

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongod
Unit mongod.service could not be found.
```

Why my strapi is working without MongoDB? What DB is this strapi using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQlite, that select menu is a bug on the AdminUI

Comment: Aha, I see. I got access my db by `sqlite3 .tmp/data.db`. Thank you!